# How should I offer a download and navigate to a "thank you" page?

Tags: javascript, http, download

I've got a website that needs to offer file(s) for download and then navigate to a "*thank you*" style page.

My approach so far has been to use `window.location = "..."` twice - first to get the browser to download the file, and then again to redirect the user to the "*thank you*" page.

Like this simplified example:

```
function do_download(filename) {
  window.location = "/files/" + filename;
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location = "/files/thankyou";
  }, 750);
}
```

This worked well for Chrome throughout the development and testing of this site but using Firefox, IE, or Edge presents an issue - the user never sees the file download and is instead just redirected to the "*thank you*" page. From the server's point of view, the request is made and subsequently aborted.

Changing the 750 ms timeout to 2.5 seconds makes this much more reliable for such browsers, but now we seem to have a timing issue, which I've confirmed...

If it takes longer than the timeout to make a request and started getting a response, then the download will be discarded/aborted and the situation will be "*broken*" (i.e: no file download, just redirected to "*thank you*").

I have confirmed this by using the 2.5 second delay in the JavaScript, and inserting a 3 second delay in the server:

- a delay "*before response headers are sent*" results in the broken behavior
- a delay "*after the response headers and first few chunks of the file are sent*", results in expected behavior

These observations appear to hold true across all browsers - so perhaps Chrome is faster at making requests, masking the initial issue.

---

Using a "*large*" timeout is not suitable, as this situation can still occur if the server or network is busy, or latency is high.

`window.open()` is not suitable, as Chrome, Firefox and Edge all block the "*popup*", which cannot subsequently be opened because of the navigation away from the original page.

---

This leads me to my question:

- How should I present a file for download **and** redirect the user to a "*thank you*" page in a more robust way?

Comment: 1. the download button is a link that has `target="_blank"`. This will open a new tab, but if the server sends a file, the tab should close right away again. 2. the click also triggers "thank you"

Comment: Can you push the download to the "Thank You"-page? Create a string `onclick` containing the path to the file and send this to next page where to show the "Thank You" and download can start.

Comment: @ChrisG thanks for the suggestion - unfortunately the download needs to be initiated by javascript (there is a process that must be performed to authenticate the download)

Comment: @SimonJensen I think I've found a workable solution for now, but I'll bear that in mind, thanks

Comment: @SimonJensen - Probably worth posting that as an answer. That's how a *lot* of sites seem to do this.

Comment: @Attie Regarding my suggestion, you can use JavaScript to simulate a link being clicked. Just call `.click()` on the `<a>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sort of thing, I've used a zero-height `iframe` as the target for the download link, had the server provide a cookie with the file response, and watched for the cookie to appear:

```
function do_download(filename) {
  // Trigger the download in the zero-height iframe
  iframe.contentWindow.location = "/files/" + filename;
  var handle = setInterval(function() {
    if (checkForCookie()) {
      window.location = "/files/thankyou";
    }
  }, 100);
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Give up
    clearInterval(handle);
    // ...probably show an error...
  }, 20000);
}
```

The cookie generally appears when the download *begins*, so there isn't a long delay.

---

You've said in a comment:

> This works really well for Chrome and Firefox, but IE and Edge still require ~2 seconds before finally performing the window.location = "/files/thankyou", otherwise the download is never presented. At least the cookie gives us a fairly solid point to start the timer...?

@Attie - Blech. :-) I guess that's because it destroys the iframe. Sadly, I think any fixed time interval like that will leave you open to failures (for instance, if the download takes a bit longer than usual). (The times I've used this in the wild, the main page was staying put, I just wanted to remove a spinner I'd shown when they click the download link.)

I think [Simon Jensen's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52871796/how-should-i-offer-a-download-and-navigate-to-a-thank-you-page/52871910?noredirect=1#comment92657378_52871796) makes sense: Pass the file as a query parameter to the thank you page, have the thank you page initiate the download. That's how a lot of sites I've used do it. (Or if you don't want it to be a query parameter, you could use [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).)

Another option is to leave the page in place, and just modify the DOM to say thank you (which is more in line with how I've used this cookie trick in the past).

Comment: Very elegant, I'll give it a go.

Comment: This works really well for Chrome and Firefox, but IE and Edge still require ~2 seconds before finally performing the `window.location = "/files/thankyou"`, otherwise the download is never presented. At least the cookie gives us a fairly solid point to start the timer...?